# prepopulate text boxes dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cfml

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw584.png)

Below is the code that takes all the Serial numbers and set each serial to the textboxes
How to add text boxes dynamically based on the Serial count.

```
$("#SerialList #" + key).val(value);
if(key == "SERIALNO_LIST")
{
    var array = value.split(",");
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        j = i + 1;
    }
    $("#SerialList #OLDSERIAL" + j).val(array[i].trim());
}
```

EDIT function:

```
function insertRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById('createTable');
  var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length - 1);
   for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < numOfCols; colIndex++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.id = "SERIAL" + cellIndex;
    input.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    return SerialAutoComplete(this);
    });
    cell.appendChild(input);        
    cellIndex++;
  }
}

<div id="editSerialList" title="Edit Engine Build">
<B>Group Name:</B>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="GROUPNAME" size="50"/>
<table cellpadding="10" id="EditTable">
<tr><td colspan="4"><div id="STATUSDIVID"  style="width:580px;"></div></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="BATCHNO" name="BATCHNO"></td></tr>
 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="OLDSERIAL1" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete1(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="OLDSERIAL2" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete1(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="OLDSERIAL3" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete1(this)" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="OLDSERIAL4" onfocus="SerialAutoComplete1(this)" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="add-users">Add Users:</td>
      <td colspan="3" style="border:none; padding:8px;">
        <select id="addUsers2" name="addUsers2" multiple="multiple"></select>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" name="AddRow" id="AddRow" class="button-green engineCancel" onClick="insertRow1()" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

If my value count is 5 , I need to add 5 textboxes before setting the textboxes, i.e. pre-populate /add text boxes before I could set the values.

Comment: But you haven't asked any question

Comment: How can I add text boxes dyamically based on count of  $("#SerialList #"+key).val(value)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array()` with number passed as parameter and `Array.prototype.fill()` with `"<input>"` passed as parameter, `Array.prototype.join()` with `""` as parameter, `.insertAdjacentHTML()` to append HTML string to specific element within `document`

```js
let n = 5;

document.body
.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", Array(n).fill("<input>").join(""));
```

alternatively using `String.prototype.repeat()`

```js
let n = 5;

document.body
.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<input>".repeat(n));
```

Comment: this adds text boxes on the main page, but how would I use in a specific page using an ID?

Comment: Substitute `document.getElementById("id")` for `document.body`

Comment: I have added my HTML and JS code, I am already generating textboxes dynamically on edit button but I need to write another function where I could prepopulate /add text boxes based on count of serial, The text boxes should be in the format that I have shown in the code above. Also, I tried adding ur code but its not adding based on count

Comment: @shwetha What is issue with `insertRow` function? Where is `numOfCols` defined?

Comment: var cellIndex = document.querySelectorAll('td>input[id^="SERIAL"]').length || 1;
var cellIndex1 = document.querySelectorAll('td>input[id^="OLDSERIAL"]').length || 1;
var numOfCols = 4;                                                                                                       InsertRow is the function similar to InsertRow1 but is called on create new group whereas InsertRow1 is called on click of Edit, I have also sent the image what my textboxes look like and after adding your code

Comment: @shwetha Consider including all necessary portions of inquiry at original Question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask